# Ruby inline fails the rails server to start in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, image-science

The application requires Image science which is dependent on Ruby Inline. After a tough time installing Image science and ruby inline, the gems were successfully installed. But when I tried to start the server it fails saying that the gcc was passed wrong parameters. The output has been attached. 
Some pointers told me to edit the ruby configuration file. But they were related to using VC++ and not gcc. Anybody facing similar issue?
I am using Rails 3, ruby 1.9.2, image science 1.2.1, ruby inline 3.9.0

`` gcc: $(if: No such file or directory
gcc: $(filter-out: No such file or directory
gcc: $(DEFFILE): No such file or directory
gcc: unrecognized option `-shared'
In file included from C:\Ruby192\include\ruby-1.9.1\ruby.h:32,
                 from C:/Users/Webyana Tech/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_cdab.c:1:
C:\Ruby192\include\ruby-1.9.1\ruby/ruby.h:64: stdint.h: No such file or directory
C:\Ruby192\include\ruby-1.9.1\ruby/ruby.h:67: inttypes.h: No such file or directory
In file included from C:\Ruby192\include\ruby-1.9.1\ruby/intern.h:29,
                 from C:\Ruby192\include\ruby-1.9.1\ruby/ruby.h:1327,
                 from C:\Ruby192\include\ruby-1.9.1\ruby.h:32,
                 from C:/Users/Webyana Tech/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_cdab.c:1:
C:\Ruby192\include\ruby-1.9.1\ruby/st.h:30: stdint.h: No such file or directory
C:\Ruby192\include\ruby-1.9.1\ruby/st.h:33: inttypes.h: No such file or directory
C:/Users/Webyana Tech/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_cdab.c:2: FreeImage.h: No such file or directory
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/RubyInline-3.8.6/lib/inline.rb:590:in `build': error executing "gcc -shared $(if $(filter-out -g -g0,-g),,-s)   -W
l,--enable-auto-image-base,--enable-auto-import $(DEFFILE)   -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wn
o-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -I C:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I C:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I C:/Ruby192/include -LC:/
Ruby192/lib -o \"C:/Users/Webyana Tech/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_cdab.so\" \"C:/Users/Webyana Tech/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_cdab.c\" -l
freeimage -lfreeimage -lstdc++  -Wl,--enable-auto-import -LC:/Ruby192/lib -lmsvcrt-ruby18": pid 5508 exit 1 (CompilationError)
Renamed C:/Users/Webyana Tech/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_cdab.c to C:/Users/Webyana Tech/.ruby_inline/Inline_ImageScience_cdab.c.bad
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/RubyInline-3.8.6/lib/inline.rb:828:in `inline'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/image_science-1.2.1/lib/image_science.rb:90:in `<class:ImageScience>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/image_science-1.2.1/lib/image_science.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Webyana Tech/Desktop/Rails3/wy_editor/config/application.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>' ``